# Why CSS background transition is not smooth?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate my header background images but transition is not smooth like I saw in tutorial.
(Ignore the gradient)

```
animation: slide 10s infinite;
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
            ),url("imgs/header-1.jpg");
    }

    33% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
            ),url("imgs/header-2.jpg");
    }

    67% {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
            ),url("imgs/header-3.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please make an executable snippet in the question? It would be nice to understand how it behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**:
Although according to documentation `background-image` property can not be animated, it may work in some environments. For example, the chrome browser allows to display transitions for `background-image`. However, it should include only `url(/path/to/img)` without any other properties. So in your case, **just remove all the gradient definitions** in keyframes, like this:

```
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        background-image: url("imgs/header-1.jpg");
    }

    33% {
        background-image: url("imgs/header-2.jpg");
    }

    67% {
        background-image: url("imgs/header-3.jpg");
    }
}
```

**Reliable approach**:

Ok, so the main issue in your code is that `background-image` property should not be animated.
However, it is possible to achieve the desired transition effect: you need to have multiple blocks with images placed one above another and just change their opacity each few seconds. The `opacity` property can be animated, so the general effect will be smooth.

Here is an example:

```css
@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.animated-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: fadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.animated-image:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.animated-image:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.animated-image:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.image-1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/299/400/400.jpg?hmac=JWLtcI8nmHDFvbS34TW5_MfzwOHSkXpWDLoXlNLyfAA);
}

.image-2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/147/400/400.jpg?hmac=EtobpNQI_FLctas3TyOZMRQX362T9SCJs1rvd1S7d8Y);
}

.image-3 {
  background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/906/400/400.jpg?hmac=VO0HSf238e6GuEC7_yx1TKPO9Z0iZgl7BgmoWyjNbXo);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="animated-image image-1"></div>
  <div class="animated-image image-2"></div>
  <div class="animated-image image-3"></div>
</div>
```

Note, that you can do this trick with any type of HTML element, so you may use `img` tag instead of divs with `background-image` if you like.

Comment: Hmm, will try your method. But how this guy is animating background-image? 
[link] (https://youtu.be/Vr4Ay4td3xU)

Comment: @NileshBhatia, seems it works in some environments despite the documentation says. I figured out, that your code will work at least in chrome if you remove the gradient definitions keyframes. I've updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

`background-image` is one of the CSS properties that cannot be animated according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

It may be working in some places but it's not a standard behavior.

Comment: I replaced `background-image` with `background` but no change.

Comment: `background` is only a shorthand for many background properties including `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

I animated my background and tested it on Edge, Firefox, and Chrome and worked on all of them.
This is my working code with React and Tailwind, However, it should not be different on pure JS and CSS:

```
import React from "react";

const Showcase = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-[url('../images/YOUR-BG-IMAGE.jpeg')] bg-top animate-background"></div>
  );
};

export default Showcase;
```

and for animation in tailwind.config.js (You can easily do it on CSS) you should add the keyframe and animation.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {extend: {keyframes: {bg: {
          "0%, 100%": {
            "background-position": "top",
          },
          "50%": {
            "background-position": "bottom",
          },
        },
      },animation: {"background": "bg 15s linear infinite",
      },
    },
  },};
```

That's it. Now you should import your component on a page(or use the code as HTML) and see the results.
Good luck :)